# Find relation between two entities in Freebase

Tags: api, freebase, mql

I am new in Freebase and I have a simple question . I would like to use Freebase KB to find relation between two entities. For example if I have name entities "Washington" and "United States" , I would like to send a query to Freebase and get :
Location/Location/Capital or Null in the case of No relation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to go one ply out (ie nearest neighbors), this is pretty simple to do using the reflection API if you're using the online version of Freebase.  If you're using the bulk downloads, you'll need to work with whatever query engine you're using (probably SPARQL unless you converted the RDF to something else).

If you want to find the shortest path(es) regardless of who far apart they are, it becomes a graph search algorithm.

EDIT: If you only want to find capitols, you can fill in your IDs in this query:

```
[{
  "type": "/location/administrative_division_capital_relationship",
  "capital": [{
    "id": null
  }],
  "administrative_division": [{
    "id": null
  }],
  "limit": 1
}]
```

Note that for Washington, D.C., this will return null because the data isn't in Freebase.

If you need to handle arbitrary properties, you'll need to use reflection.  See https://developers.google.com/freebase/mql/ch03#reflection

Comment: Thanks Tom but can you give me a suggestion for Query? I am using online API to access Freebase and lets say I would like have to maximum 3 level distance between entities as I mentioned above (Location/Location/Contain) . i have Guid of th entities , so I can search by GUID